# javascript : input field back to default value when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a `form` w/ radio button to select so other input field will hide.

I just want, if input field hide value will turn to default.

**javascript**

```
<script>
function showhidediv( rad )
    {
        var rads = document.getElementsByName( rad.name );
        document.getElementById( 'one' ).style.display = ( rads[0].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.getElementById( 'two' ).style.display = ( rads[1].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.getElementById( 'three' ).style.display = ( rads[2].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
</script>
```

**form**

```
<form action="aef.php" method="post">
  <label>Date</label><br />
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" name="date" /><br /><br />

  <input type="radio" name="transtype" value="0" onclick="showhidediv(this);" checked /> LBC Payment
  <input type="radio" name="transtype" value="1" onclick="showhidediv(this);" /> Additional Funds
  <input type="radio" name="transtype" value="2" onclick="showhidediv(this);" /> miscellaneous expense

  <br /><br />
  <div id="one">

   <label>LBC Tracking No.</label><br />
   <input type="text" value="" name="lbc" /><br /><br />

   <label>Transaction Code</label><br />
   <input type="text" value="" name="code" id="code" /><br /><br />

   <label>Credit Amout</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="credit_amount" />

   <br /><br /><p>Available funds : <?php echo $ab; ?></p>

  </div>

  <div id="two" class="divhide">
    <label>Debit Amout</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="debit_amount" />
  </div>

  <div id="three" class="divhide">
    <label>Expenses Description</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="expenses" value="" name="description" /><br /><br />

    <label>miscellaneous expense</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="credit_amount2" />

    <br /><br /><p>Available funds : <?php echo $ab; ?></p>
  </div>


  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Expenses" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is save the default values of the inputs and then insert them back whenever you need them.

For example:

```
var inputVal = document.getElementById('input1').value;

//When input value is hidden, insert value
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('input1').value = inputVal;
```